# Keras, wrong input shape, but x.shape is right

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Trying to set up a neural network using Keras in python.

I get this error when trying to predict with my neural network:

`ValueError: Error when checking : expected input_1 to have shape (12,) but got array with shape (1,)`

However if i `print(x.shape)` it returns as (12,)

This is the code block:

```
def predict(str):
    y = convert(str)
    x = data = np.array(y, dtype='int64') 

    with graph.as_default():
        print(x.shape);
        #perform the prediction
        out = model.predict(x)
        print(out)
        print(np.argmax(out,axis=1))
        print ("debug3")
        #convert the response to a string
        response = np.array_str(np.argmax(out,axis=1))
        return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keras models often hide the *batch size*, so actually it is `(samples, 12)` and each sample has 12 features. In your case what happens is you have 12 samples each with one feature; hence, it feeds `(1,)`.

Either your data is single data point and you need create a 2D array or change your model `input_shape=(1,)`.

Comment: my "x" looks like this `[         4          5         64          6 2886795266 2886795265
         22      55190          0          0          8       6041]` . The data used to tain looks the same, except its multiple lists like this within a list.

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/MZMKqTL_SWyABTOPLrgjDw.png screenshot of printed training data

Comment: I wrapped my data into another list, simply data = [data] and works now, thanks :D